# Identify if objects are the same

Tags: hp-uft

I want to check certain objects against each other and identify if they are the same.

For example, I need to verify that the total cost in one page is the same as another page. I developed a script that works, however the total cost changes every day so I have to update the object properties in maintenance mode every day.

Is there a way that UFT automatically recognizes this object must change and update?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Show how the object looks in two different days for example.

Answer (score 0):

I request you to elaborate your question. For now, you can use .* if certain values of the object are changing. Alternatively, you can store the values in an excel sheet and you can change everyday depending on the requirement.

If this is not helpful let me know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want to compare the values shown in two different objects, and see if those values are the same. (I assume this because you say they are on two different pages)

Also, you mention maintenance mode, so I assume you are using checkpoints to store their expected values.

I would suggest: instead of storing the expected values in a checkpoint, you could read the value of the first object (getROproperty), store it in a variable (dataTable field, environment variable, etc), and then navigate to the other page, read the ROproperty from the other object, and then compare.

i.e.

```
if {browser,page,object...}.getROproperty({whateverPropertyYouNeed}) = environment({storedFirstValue}) then

  reporter.reportevent micPass,"compare step","{details here}"

end if
```

*replace stuff inside {} with your code, I don't know what it is

If you need to actually store the total cost externally, you could use a DataTable field and export the sheets at the end.  then import the same sheet at the beginning.  That would save the data to an excel sheet on a drive.